# What happened during Kartikeya's creation period?

Tags: creation, kartikeya

Some days ago, learned about Brahma Sastha, a form of Lord Kartikeya. The Upadesha Khanda of Sankara Samhita of Skanda Purana narrates Lord Kartikeya temporary doing creation, which implies this form.

It is interesting and i ask a question about it. My question is, what happens during Kartikeya's creation period? Does any other scriptures mentions that?

Comment: Just note that you are adding identification request tag to almost all questions you are asking but that tag should be limited to  only "where is this verse located in scriptures?" type of questions or to "which deity is in this image?" type. Thanks.

Comment: @Rickross ok, i fixed it.

Comment: Thanks Boovanaes ....